# Button/dropdown button disabled by default without specifying disabled

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a dropdown button in my react project and its rendering as disabled by default. why is this happening ?

The first dropdown is working fine, i called the same dropdown in the navbar after this one and it renders as disabled. I tried other things as well, like adding a button also would not work for me.

The navbar is diplayed when i get a response from the backend and a different component is rendered (ResultTable)

```
import React from "react";
import ResultTable from "./ResultTable";
...
import DropdownButton from "react-bootstrap/DropdownButton";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";

class MainContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     //more state values
      threshold: 0.75
    };
    this.thresholdChange = this.thresholdChange.bind(this);
  }
  thresholdChange(input) {
    this.setState({
      threshold: input
    });
  }

  toProperCase = function (txt) {
    return txt.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
  };

  render() {
    const { responseData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container-flex container-without-scroll wrapper"     
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${bg})`,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100vh",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        overFlow:'hidden'
      }}
    >
            <div
              className={`container-fluid `}>                        
              {this.state.displayTable ? (
                <Navbar
                  style={{
                    position: "fixed",
                    left: "50%",
                    top: "95%",
                    transform: "translate(-50%, -90%)",
                    backgroundColor: 'black'
                  }}
                  sticky="bottom"
                >
                   <br />
                  <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">

                    <Button
                      variant="primary"
                      disabled={
                        this.props.initialTransaction &&
                          this.props.initialTransaction.version == 0 &&
                          this.props.initialTransaction
                          ? true
                          : false
                      }

                      size="sm"
                      style={{ color: "#FFF" }}
                      onClick={this.undoAction}
                    >
                      <span className=" fa fa-undo "></span>
                      &nbsp;Undo
                  </Button>
                    &nbsp;  &nbsp;

                  <Button
                      variant="primary"
                      size="sm"
                      style={{ color: "#FFF" }}
                      disabled={
                        (this.props.initialTransaction &&
                          this.props.initialTransaction.version) <
                          (this.props.currentVersion &&
                            this.props.currentVersion.version)
                          ? false
                          : true
                      }
                      onClick={this.redoAction}
                    >
                      <span className=" fa fa-repeat "></span>
                      &nbsp;Redo
                  </Button>
                    &nbsp;  &nbsp;
                  <Button
                      variant="success"
                      size="sm"
                      style={{ color: "#FFF" }}
                      disabled={
                        this.props.initialTransaction &&
                          this.props.initialTransaction.version == 0
                          ? true
                          : false
                      }
                      onClick={() =>
                        this.exportExcel(this.props.initialTransaction)
                      }
                    >
                      <span className=" fa fa-download "></span>
                      &nbsp;Export
                  </Button>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp; <DropdownButton
                        size="md"
                        title={this.state.threshold}
                      >&nbsp;
                        {this.state.thresholdValues.map(eachValue => {
                        return (
                          <Dropdown.Item
                            key = {Math.random()}
                            onClick={() => this.thresholdChange(eachValue)}
                            as="button"
                          >
                            {eachValue}
                          </Dropdown.Item>
                        );
                      })}
                      </DropdownButton>
                  </Navbar.Collapse>
                  <br/>
                </Navbar>
              ) : null}

              {this.state.displayTable ? null : (
                <div
                  className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: "50%",
                    top: "50%",
                    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(14, 13, 13, 0.74)'
                  }}
                >
                  <br />
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-group col-md-9">
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <div className="input-group-prepend">
                        <span
                        style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                          onClick={this.onFormSubmit}
                          className="input-group-text"
                          id="inputGroupFileAddon01"
                        >
                          {" "}
                          Upload{" "}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div className="custom-file">
                        <input
                          type="file"
                          className="custom-file-input"
                          id="inputGroupFile01"
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01"
                        />
                        <label
                          className="custom-file-label"
                          htmlFor="inputGroupFile01"
                        >
                          {this.props.active && this.props.active.filename}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                      <DropdownButton
                        size="md"
                        id="dropdown-item-button"
                        title={this.state.threshold}
                      >&nbsp;
                        {this.state.thresholdValues.map(eachValue => {
                        return (
                          <Dropdown.Item
                            onClick={() => this.thresholdChange(eachValue)}
                            as="button"
                          >
                            {eachValue}
                          </Dropdown.Item>

                        );
                      })}
                      </DropdownButton>

                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <br />
                </div>
              )}
                <div >
                  {this.state.displayTable ? (
                    <div className = "container-flex" style = 
              {{overflowY:'scroll', maxHeight:'80vh'}}>
                    <ResultTable
                      data={responseData}
                      afterMerge={params => {
                        this.afterMerge(params);
                      }}
                    />
                    </div>
                  ) : null}
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        );
      }
    }

    // Maps state from store to props
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {

      };
    };

    // Maps actions to props
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {

      };
    };

    // Use connect to put them together
    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(MainContainer);
```

Comment: Without specific code examples, it's difficult to answer this question. Please edit your question to include some or all of your code.

Comment: @benjamin Soyka - I added the code and some more explanation.